# PostgreSQL: Creating a large number of views

Tags: postgresql, transactions, view

I am witnessing a strange behavior from Postgres. Here's what I am doing:

I tried creating 10,000 **temporary** views as follows

```
psqlStatement.executeUpdate("CREATE OR REPLACE TEMP VIEW " + symbols.get(i) + " AS SELECT * from persons;");
```

After creating around 9000 views I started getting error "out of shared memory. Hint: You might need to increase max_locks_per_transaction"

I took the hint and changed the value from 64 (which is the default) to 100 in `postgresql.conf` file. After changing this value, I was unable to start the Postgres server. If I change the value back to 64 or 65, the server starts.

To further investigate the issue, instead of creating 10,000 views, I created 8,000 views which was successful. I started the Postgres console and wrote the query to display all the views and I got the same error (out of shared memory. Hint: You might...) **again**.

So to summarize I am seeing 3 strange things:

1) Even though I made temporary views and my main method (from which I am creating the views) exits gracefully, why are the views still present in the db? I did

```
SELECT count(*) from pg_views
WHERE schemaname NOT IN('information_schema', 'pg_catalog');
```

and it returned 8,000.

2) Why doesn't the Postgres server start if `max_locks_per_transaction` has got a higher value than 64 (in accordance with the hint)?

3) How can I make a lot of views without running into 'out of shared memory' errors?

Comment: did you try to run this with autocommit or commit after e.g. a 100 views?

Comment: I dint actually do any commits..i made the views from a java application using the executeUpdate statement in a loop

Comment: So did you run with autocommit? Did you try to do some commits?

Comment: Have you read this page?: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/kernel-resources.html

Comment: The issue with Pg not starting is probably because you've reached the operating system's limits on shared memory. See @kgrittn's link. If Pg doesn's start, look at the PostgreSQL logs for a reason; it'll often explain what's going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1) Even though I made temporary views and my main method (from which I
>   am creating the views) exits gracefully, why are the views still
>   present in the db?

Temporary objects persist for the duration of the *session* (not just the transaction). You'll have to close the session or delete the objects to remove them from the system catalog - logically. Physically, a dead tuple stays behind until `VACUUM FULL` or reuse ...).

Even temporary objects have entries in (non-temporary) system catalog. (That's why creating temporary tables / views triggers disk writes.) Therefore, querying `SELECT count(*) from pg_views` yields the same number from *any* session and as long as the owning session did not terminate.